# Textwatcher changes on Editable in afterTextChanged does not affect the Editable itself

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I'm trying to implement a filter on an edit text where I need to filter non digit characters and dot. I could use the digit tag of Edit Text or input type but it seems there has been slight difference between devices like there are devices that shows dot character even when you filter them within the EditText.

Here's the afterTextChanged method

```
if(isEditing) return;
            Log.v("Information", "last: " + s.charAt(s.length()-1));
            Log.v("Information", "Full string before: " + s.toString());
            if(s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '.') {
                Log.v("Information", "DOT!");
                isEditing = true;
                String currentText = s.toString().replace(".", "");
                s.replace(0, s.length(),  currentText);
                isEditing = false;
                Log.v("Information", "Full string after: " + s.toString());
                return;
            }
            else if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(s.length()-1))) {
                Log.v("Information", "NOT DIGIT!");
                isEditing = true;
                String currentText = "";
                if(s.length() > 1)
                    currentText = s.toString().substring(0, s.length()-1);
                s.replace(0, s.length(), currentText);
                isEditing = false;
                Log.v("Information", "Full string after: " + s.toString());
                return;
            }
```

And here's the output

```
last: 6
Full string before: 6
Full string after: 6
last: 6
Full string before: 66
Full string after: 66
last: h
Full string before: 66h
NOT DIGIT!
Full string after: 66
last: h
Full string before: 66hh
NOT DIGIT!
Full string after: 66h
```

As you can see, after i delete the first 'h', when i input another h, string becomes "66hh" where it should be "66h" because i already deleted the first h. What can cause to prevent my change on the editable s?

Edit:
Forgot to mention, here's my EditText

```
 <core.globals.views.EditTextWithCursorWatcher
                    android:id="@+id/edittext"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:hint="0,00"
                    android:maxLength="15"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="0,00"
                    android:textColor="#ff414141"
                    android:textColorHint="#ff414141"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Try using `currentText = s.toString().replace(s.substring(s.length() - 1), "");`

Comment: I don't think the problem lies within the currentText. "Full string after: 66" after i insert 'h' implies that my delete is confirmed which means currentText is working. The problem is that after the second 'h' is inserted, "Full string before: 66hh" should be "Full string before: 66".

Comment: that you want only digits to enter?

Comment: Digits plus comma. But changing the input types or declaring digit:0123... or filtering using input filter not working for some devices. Some devices always show the dot no matter how i filtered them.

Comment: I'm not sure why but changing the editable from the EditText object and not the editable from the method parameter solved it...

Answer (score 0):

I just create working demo using custom Inputfilter. Just try this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText edtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);

        InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

                try {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(0))) {
                        if (source.equals(",")) {
                            if (dend == 0) {
                                return "";
                            } else {
                                if (("" + edtText.getText().toString().charAt(edtText.getText().toString().length() - 1)).equals(",")) {
                                    return "";
                                } else {
                                    return null;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        edtText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });

    }
```

Comment: I removed the text watcher and implemented your filter to my EditText, filter doesn't affect at all on samsung devices (Samsung Tab 3).